# Symfony 2: Custom form type with mandatory constraints

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have complicated constraint for validating my field. However now I would like to use it in multiple forms. The fields would have little bit more common (label, etc.).

However in one in one place I would need to add NotBlank constraint and thats where my problem begins.

Normally I would add my CustomConstraint into default constraints in `setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface)` function but it will be rewritten when I add additionl constraint thus removing benefit of having custom field type.

Is there a way how to set mandatory constraint or creating custom OptionResolver?

Comment: NOTE: This question is outdated, and I no-longer have access to the affected code, and I'm not able to test any provided solution. :-\

Answer (score 0):

What about creating an option called `additional_constraints`, defaulted to empty array, but if you set constraints into it, it adds them (in `buildForm`) to the `constraints` option of your Type?

Comment: `additional_constraints`? But than I could simply add the Constraint in `buildForm` which does not seem to work.
`class CustomType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $options['constraints'][] = new MyCustomConstraint();
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
    }

    public function getParent() {
        return 'text';
    }`